# Add few records to NS record via awscli

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cli

Help me please create an NS record with few records via awscli. It creates with one record, but errors with few records:

```
#!/bin/bash
function change_batch2() {
    jq -c -n "{\"Changes\": [{\"Action\": \"UPSERT\", \"ResourceRecordSet\": {\"Name\": \"cluster.domain_name.\", \"Type\": \"NS\", \"TTL\": 60, \"ResourceRecords\": [{\"Value\": \"record1. record2.\"} ] } } ] }"
}
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <ZONE_ID> --change-batch $(change_batch2) | jq -r '.ChangeInfo.Id' | cut -d'/' -f3
```

After this I've an error:

```
A client error (InvalidChangeBatch) occurred when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: [Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: RRDATANotSingleField (Value contains spaces) encountered with 'record1.
record2.']
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Here's one that worked for me in a script I previously wrote: `aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $ZONE_TAG --change-batch '{"Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"'$NAME_TAG'","Type":"A","TTL":300,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"'$MY_IP'"}]}}]}'`. See: [Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've added an error text above. It doesn't "like" some sign. I've tried \n, \\n,\r\n but it doesn't create NS record with few records divided by "enter". I think it's possible to do because I can create it manually and thus I suppose the error is in the JSON part of the command.

Comment: Did you try my version of the command (with your values)? It didn't need any escape characters.

Comment: Your script is much better. I've tried it and it works with one value for NS record. But with few records in give me the same error.
```A client error (InvalidChangeBatch) occurred when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: [Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: RRDATANotSingleField (Value contains spaces) encountered with 'record1 record2']
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the command you used, and the error, so that we can attempt to reproduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded and helped me.
I've found a solution here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232605
and applied it to. I've written all names without any spaces - just in one line. At least it works for me. The syntax is similar:

```
...\"ResourceRecords\": [{\"Value\": \"record1.record2.\"} ] } } ] }"
```

Answer (score 5):

I've found answer. You should use such json syntax:

```
\"ResourceRecords\": [{\"Value\": \"record1.\"},{\"Value\": \"record2.\"} ]
```

Comment: That's it, worked for me when calling from file (as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/simple-resource-record-route53-cli/) ) even on separate lines:
```"ResourceRecords": [ { "Value": "ns1." },
                                    { "Value": "ns2." } ]```